# I18n.translate(:countries) doesnt return countries for some locales

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, internationalization, i18n-gem

I have a very strange issue. I have 6 locales (en, ca, es, es_PE, es_MX, es_Cl)

If i type `I18n.translate(:countries)` It returns the countries for some locales and other locales it returns: `"translation missing: es-PE.countries"`

I have 6 country files in config/locales called:

```
localized_country_select.es.rb
localized_country_select.es_MX.rb
localized_country_select.es_PE.rb
localized_country_select.en.rb
etc etc
```

This all occurred after a bundle update and I cant find some errors in the localized country files. I even tested it in a new app and the localized country files worked just fine.

This issue was bugging me a couple of hours yesterday and really no clue... A little help would be highly appreciated.

Some info:

Gemfile:

source 'http://rubygems.org'

```
gem 'rails', '~> 3.1.2'
gem 'rack', '~> 1.3.5'

gem 'puma'

group :production do
  gem 'unicorn'
end

gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'

gem 'yajl-ruby' # Speedy JSON
gem 'couchrest_model', git: 'https://github.com/samlown/couchrest_model.git'

# Asset template engines
group 'assets' do
  gem 'sass-rails', '3.1.4'
  gem 'haml-rails'
  gem 'coffee-script'
  gem 'uglifier'
  gem "compass-rails"
end

gem 'jquery-rails'

gem 'therubyracer', :require => false

gem 'geokit'
gem 'geocoder'
gem 'pr_geohash'

gem 'roadie'

gem "gravatar", "~> 1.0"

# SMS related gubbins
gem "e164"
gem "textmagic"

gem 'formtastic'

# Handle money gracefully
gem 'money', '~> 5.0.0'
# For exchange rates
gem 'money-open-exchange-rates', git: "git://github.com/MaxiMobility/money-open-exchange-rates.git"

gem 'state_machine'

gem 'airbrake'

gem 'adyen'

gem 'spreadsheet'

gem 'gettext_i18n_rails'
gem 'localized_country_select', :git => 'https://github.com/samlown/localized_country_select.git', :branch => 'master'

gem 'bluecloth'

gem 'resque', :require => 'resque/server'
gem 'resque_mailer'
gem 'resque-timeout'

gem 'aws-ses', :require => 'aws/ses'#, :git => "http://github.com/teeparham/aws-ses.git", :ref => "eca27d0517"

gem 'twitter'

gem 'kaminari'

gem 'carrierwave'
gem 'fog'
gem 'mini_magick'

gem 'prawn'

gem 'useragent'

# Authorization
gem 'cancan'

# Solves the pain of uploading files + AJAX
gem "remotipart"

gem 'whenever', :require => false

group :development do
  gem 'web_translate_it', :require => false
  gem 'nifty-generators'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 2.6'
  gem 'thin'

  gem 'debugger'

  # Deployments
  gem 'capistrano'
  gem 'capistrano-ext'
  gem "capistrano_rsync_with_remote_cache", "~> 2.4.0"

  # Used for compiling .po and .mo files
  gem 'gettext', '>=1.9.3', :require => false
  gem 'ruby_parser', :require => false

  # Used by localised_country_select to import languages
  gem 'hpricot'

  # Testing javascript
  gem "jasminerice"
  gem 'headless'
end

group :test do
  # Pretty printed test output
  gem 'turn', :require => false
  gem 'steak'
  gem 'rack-test'
  gem 'rspec'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails'
  gem 'autotest'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 2.6'
  gem 'guard-rspec'
  gem 'capybara'
  # Ensure QT kit is installed: brew install qt
  gem 'capybara-webkit'
  gem 'launchy'
  # Avoid RubyGems 1.8 issues with this gem:
  gem 'ZenTest', '~> 4.5.0'
  # Testing javascript
  gem "jasminerice"
end
```

This is the diff of my bundle update (biggest change is Rails 3.1.8).

Gemfile:

```
-gem 'rails', '3.1.2'
+gem 'rails', '~> 3.1.2'

group 'assets' do
-  gem 'sass-rails'
+  gem 'sass-rails', '3.1.4'
end
```

Gemfile.lock

```
-    Ascii85 (1.0.1)
+    Ascii85 (1.0.2)
+    actionmailer (3.1.8)
+      actionpack (= 3.1.8)
+      mail (~> 2.3.3)
+    actionpack (3.1.8)
+      activemodel (= 3.1.8)
+      activesupport (= 3.1.8)
-      rack (~> 1.3.5)
-      rack-cache (~> 1.1)
+      rack (~> 1.3.6)
+      rack-cache (~> 1.2)
-      sprockets (~> 2.1.0)
-    activemodel (3.1.2)
-      activesupport (= 3.1.2)
+      sprockets (~> 2.0.4)
+    activemodel (3.1.8)
+      activesupport (= 3.1.8)
-    activerecord (3.1.2)
-      activemodel (= 3.1.2)
-      activesupport (= 3.1.2)
-      arel (~> 2.2.1)
+    activerecord (3.1.8)
+      activemodel (= 3.1.8)
+      activesupport (= 3.1.8)
+      arel (~> 2.2.3)
-    activeresource (3.1.2)
-      activemodel (= 3.1.2)
-      activesupport (= 3.1.2)
-    activesupport (3.1.2)
-      multi_json (~> 1.0)
-    addressable (2.2.8)
-    adyen (1.3.0)
-    airbrake (3.0.5)
-      activesupport
+    activeresource (3.1.8)
+      activemodel (= 3.1.8)
+      activesupport (= 3.1.8)
+    activesupport (3.1.8)
+      multi_json (>= 1.0, < 1.3)
+    addressable (2.3.2)
+    adyen (1.3.1)
+    airbrake (3.1.4)
-    ansi (1.3.0)
+      girl_friday
+    ansi (1.4.3)
-    cancan (1.6.7)
-    capistrano (2.11.2)
+    cancan (1.6.8)
+    capistrano (2.13.4)
-    capybara (1.1.1)
+    capybara (1.1.2)
-    capybara-webkit (0.12.0)
+    capybara-webkit (0.12.1)
-    chunky_png (1.2.5)
+    chunky_png (1.2.6)
-    coffee-script-source (1.1.2)
+    coffee-script-source (1.3.3)
+    connection_pool (0.9.2)
-    debugger (1.1.3)
+    debugger (1.2.0)
-      debugger-ruby_core_source (~> 1.1.2)
-    debugger-linecache (1.1.1)
+      debugger-ruby_core_source (~> 1.1.3)
+    debugger-linecache (1.1.2)
-    debugger-ruby_core_source (1.1.2)
+    debugger-ruby_core_source (1.1.3)
-    e164 (0.3.1)
+    e164 (0.3.2)
-    execjs (1.2.9)
+    execjs (1.4.0)
-    factory_girl (2.3.0)
-      activesupport
-    factory_girl_rails (1.4.0)
-      factory_girl (~> 2.3.0)
+    factory_girl (4.1.0)
+      activesupport (>= 3.0.0)
+    factory_girl_rails (4.1.0)
+      factory_girl (~> 4.1.0)
-    fast_gettext (0.6.2)
+    fast_gettext (0.6.10)
-    fog (1.5.0)
+    fog (1.6.0)
-    formtastic (2.2.0)
+    formtastic (2.2.1)
-    geocoder (1.1.0)
-    geokit (1.6.0)
-    gettext (2.1.0)
-      locale (>= 2.0.5)
-    gettext_i18n_rails (0.3.0)
-      fast_gettext
+    geocoder (1.1.3)
+    geokit (1.6.5)
+      multi_json
+    gettext (2.3.1)
+      locale
+    gettext_i18n_rails (0.7.1)
+      fast_gettext (>= 0.4.8)
+    girl_friday (0.10.0)
+      connection_pool (~> 0.9.0)
-    guard (1.0.0)
-      ffi (>= 0.5.0)
-      thor (~> 0.14.6)
-    guard-rspec (0.6.0)
-      guard (>= 0.10.0)
+    guard (1.3.2)
+      listen (>= 0.4.2)
+      thor (>= 0.14.6)
+    guard-rspec (1.2.1)
+      guard (>= 1.1)
+    hashery (2.0.1)
-    highline (1.6.11)
+    highline (1.6.15)
-    httparty (0.8.1)
-      multi_json
+    httparty (0.9.0)
+      multi_json (~> 1.0)
-    kaminari (0.12.4)
-      rails (>= 3.0.0)
+    kaminari (0.14.1)
+      actionpack (>= 3.0.0)
+      activesupport (>= 3.0.0)
-    launchy (2.0.5)
-      addressable (~> 2.2.6)
+    launchy (2.1.2)
+      addressable (~> 2.3)
-    locale (2.0.5)
+    listen (0.5.1)
+    locale (2.0.8)
-    mini_magick (3.3)
-      subexec (~> 0.1.0)
-    mocha (0.10.0)
+    mini_magick (3.4)
+      subexec (~> 0.2.1)
+    mocha (0.12.4)
-    multi_json (1.3.6)
+    multi_json (1.2.0)
-    pdf-reader (1.0.0)
+    pdf-reader (1.2.0)
+      hashery (~> 2.0)
-    puma (1.6.2)
+    puma (1.6.3)
-    rails (3.1.2)
-      actionmailer (= 3.1.2)
-      actionpack (= 3.1.2)
-      activerecord (= 3.1.2)
-      activeresource (= 3.1.2)
-      activesupport (= 3.1.2)
+    rails (3.1.8)
+      actionmailer (= 3.1.8)
+      actionpack (= 3.1.8)
+      activerecord (= 3.1.8)
+      activeresource (= 3.1.8)
+      activesupport (= 3.1.8)
-      railties (= 3.1.2)
-    railties (3.1.2)
-      actionpack (= 3.1.2)
-      activesupport (= 3.1.2)
+      railties (= 3.1.8)
+    railties (3.1.8)
+      actionpack (= 3.1.8)
+      activesupport (= 3.1.8)
-    redis (2.2.2)
-    redis-namespace (1.0.3)
-      redis (< 3.0.0)
+    redis (3.0.1)
+    redis-namespace (1.2.1)
+      redis (~> 3.0.0)
-    resque (1.20.0)
+    resque (1.22.0)
-      redis-namespace (~> 1.0.2)
+      redis-namespace (~> 1.0)
-    resque_mailer (2.0.2)
-      actionmailer (>= 3.0.0)
-      resque (>= 1.2.3)
+    resque_mailer (2.1.0)
+      actionmailer (~> 3.0)
-    rspec (2.8.0)
-      rspec-core (~> 2.8.0)
-      rspec-expectations (~> 2.8.0)
-      rspec-mocks (~> 2.8.0)
-    rspec-core (2.8.0)
-    rspec-expectations (2.8.0)
-      diff-lcs (~> 1.1.2)
-    rspec-mocks (2.8.0)
-    rspec-rails (2.8.1)
+    rspec (2.11.0)
+      rspec-core (~> 2.11.0)
+      rspec-expectations (~> 2.11.0)
+      rspec-mocks (~> 2.11.0)
+    rspec-core (2.11.1)
+    rspec-expectations (2.11.3)
+      diff-lcs (~> 1.1.3)
+    rspec-mocks (2.11.2)
+    rspec-rails (2.11.0)
-      rspec (~> 2.8.0)
+      rspec (~> 2.11.0)
-    ruby-ole (1.2.11.3)
-    ruby-rc4 (0.1.3)
+    ruby-ole (1.2.11.4)
+    ruby-rc4 (0.1.5)
-    sass-rails (3.1.6)
+    sass-rails (3.1.4)
-      sass (>= 3.1.10)
+      sass (>= 3.1.4)
+      sprockets (~> 2.0.0)
-    sexp_processor (3.0.7)
+    sexp_processor (3.2.0)
-    sinatra (1.3.2)
+    sinatra (1.3.3)
-    spreadsheet (0.6.8)
+    spreadsheet (0.7.3)
-    sprockets (2.1.3)
+    sprockets (2.0.4)
-    state_machine (1.0.2)
+    state_machine (1.1.2)
-    subexec (0.1.0)
+    subexec (0.2.2)
-    therubyracer (0.9.10)
+    therubyracer (0.10.2)
-    turn (0.8.3)
+    turn (0.9.6)
-    twitter (3.7.0)
-      faraday (~> 0.8)
-      multi_json (~> 1.3)
-      simple_oauth (~> 0.1.6)
+    twitter (2.2.0)
+      activesupport (>= 2.3.9, < 4)
+      faraday (~> 0.7)
+      multi_json (~> 1.0)
+      simple_oauth (~> 0.1)
-    uglifier (1.0.3)
+    uglifier (1.3.0)
-      multi_json (>= 1.0.2)
+      multi_json (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.2)
-    useragent (0.4.6)
+    useragent (0.4.10)
-    web_translate_it (1.10.0)
+    web_translate_it (2.0.4)
+      json
-  rails (= 3.1.2)
+  rails (~> 3.1.2)
-  sass-rails
+  sass-rails (= 3.1.4)
```

My locale files:

localized_country.es.rb

```
    #encoding: UTF-8
    { :es_CL => {

        :countries => {
                :AC => "Isla de la Ascensión",
                :AD => "Andorra",
                :AE => "Emiratos Árabes Unidos",
                :AF => "Afganistán",
                :AG => "Antigua y Barbuda",
                :AI => "Anguila",
                :AL => "Albania",
                :AM => "Armenia",
                :AN => "Antillas Neerlandesas",
                :AO => "Angola",
                :AQ => "Antártida",
                :AR => "Argentina",
                :AS => "Samoa Americana",
                :AT => "Austria",
                :AU => "Australia",
                :AW => "Aruba",
                :AX => "Islas Åland",
                :AZ => "Azerbaiyán",
                :BA => "Bosnia-Herzegovina",
                :BB => "Barbados",
                :BD => "Bangladesh",
                :BE => "Bélgica",
                :BF => "Burkina Faso",
                :BG => "Bulgaria",
                :BH => "Bahréin",
                :BI => "Burundi",
                :BJ => "Benín",
                :BL => "San Bartolomé",
                :BM => "Bermudas",
                :BN => "Brunéi",
                :BO => "Bolivia",
                :BQ => "BQ",
                :BR => "Brasil",
                :BS => "Bahamas",
                :BT => "Bután",
                :BV => "Isla Bouvet",
                :BW => "Botsuana",
                :BY => "Bielorrusia",
                :BZ => "Belice",
                :CA => "Canadá",
                :CC => "Islas Cocos",
                :CD => "República Democrática del Congo",
                :CF => "República Centroafricana",
                :CG => "Congo - Brazzaville",
                :CH => "Suiza",
                :CI => "Costa de Marfil",
                :CK => "Islas Cook",
                :CL => "Chile",
                :CM => "Camerún",
                :CN => "China",
                :CO => "Colombia",
                :CP => "Isla Clipperton",
                :CR => "Costa Rica",
                :CS => "Serbia y Montenegro",
                :CU => "Cuba",
                :CV => "Cabo Verde",
                :CW => "CW",
                :CX => "Isla Christmas",
                :CY => "Chipre",
                :CZ => "República Checa",
                :DE => "Alemania",
                :DG => "Diego García",
                :DJ => "Yibuti",
                :DK => "Dinamarca",
                :DM => "Dominica",
                :DO => "República Dominicana",
                :DZ => "Argelia",
                :EA => "Ceuta y Melilla",
                :EC => "Ecuador",
                :EE => "Estonia",
                :EG => "Egipto",
                :EH => "Sáhara Occidental",
                :ER => "Eritrea",
                :ES => "España",
                :ET => "Etiopía",
                :EU => "Unión Europea",
                :FI => "Finlandia",
                :FJ => "Fiyi",
                :FK => "Islas Malvinas",
                :FM => "Micronesia",
                :FO => "Islas Feroe",
                :FR => "Francia",
                :GA => "Gabón",
                :GB => "Reino Unido",
                :GD => "Granada",
                :GE => "Georgia",
                :GF => "Guayana Francesa",
                :GG => "Guernsey",
                :GH => "Ghana",
                :GI => "Gibraltar",
                :GL => "Groenlandia",
                :GM => "Gambia",
                :GN => "Guinea",
                :GP => "Guadalupe",
                :GQ => "Guinea Ecuatorial",
                :GR => "Grecia",
                :GS => "Islas Georgia del Sur y Sandwich del Sur",
                :GT => "Guatemala",
                :GU => "Guam",
                :GW => "Guinea-Bissau",
                :GY => "Guyana",
                :HK => "Región Administrativa Especial de Hong Kong de la República Popular China",
                :HM => "Islas Heard y McDonald",
                :HN => "Honduras",
                :HR => "Croacia",
                :HT => "Haití",
                :HU => "Hungría",
                :IC => "Islas Canarias",
                :ID => "Indonesia",
                :IE => "Irlanda",
                :IL => "Israel",
                :IM => "Isla de Man",
                :IN => "India",
                :IO => "Territorio Británico del Océano Índico",
                :IQ => "Iraq",
                :IR => "Irán",
                :IS => "Islandia",
                :IT => "Italia",
                :JE => "Jersey",
                :JM => "Jamaica",
                :JO => "Jordania",
                :JP => "Japón",
                :KE => "Kenia",
                :KG => "Kirguistán",
                :KH => "Camboya",
                :KI => "Kiribati",
                :KM => "Comoras",
                :KN => "San Cristóbal y Nieves",
                :KP => "Corea del Norte",
                :KR => "Corea del Sur",
                :KW => "Kuwait",
                :KY => "Islas Caimán",
                :KZ => "Kazajistán",
                :LA => "Laos",
                :LB => "Líbano",
                :LC => "Santa Lucía",
                :LI => "Liechtenstein",
                :LK => "Sri Lanka",
                :LR => "Liberia",
                :LS => "Lesoto",
                :LT => "Lituania",
                :LU => "Luxemburgo",
                :LV => "Letonia",
                :LY => "Libia",
                :MA => "Marruecos",
                :MC => "Mónaco",
                :MD => "Moldavia",
                :ME => "Montenegro",
                :MF => "San Martín",
                :MG => "Madagascar",
                :MH => "Islas Marshall",
                :MK => "Macedonia",
                :ML => "Mali",
                :MM => "Myanmar [Birmania]",
                :MN => "Mongolia",
                :MO => "Región Administrativa Especial de Macao de la República Popular China",
                :MP => "Islas Marianas del Norte",
                :MQ => "Martinica",
                :MR => "Mauritania",
                :MS => "Montserrat",
                :MT => "Malta",
                :MU => "Mauricio",
                :MV => "Maldivas",
                :MW => "Malaui",
                :MX => "México",
                :MY => "Malasia",
                :MZ => "Mozambique",
                :NA => "Namibia",
                :NC => "Nueva Caledonia",
                :NE => "Níger",
                :NF => "Isla Norfolk",
                :NG => "Nigeria",
                :NI => "Nicaragua",
                :NL => "Países Bajos",
                :NO => "Noruega",
                :NP => "Nepal",
                :NR => "Nauru",
                :NU => "Isla Niue",
                :NZ => "Nueva Zelanda",
                :OM => "Omán",
                :PA => "Panamá",
                :PE => "Perú",
                :PF => "Polinesia Francesa",
                :PG => "Papúa Nueva Guinea",
                :PH => "Filipinas",
                :PK => "Pakistán",
                :PL => "Polonia",
                :PM => "San Pedro y Miquelón",
                :PN => "Islas Pitcairn",
                :PR => "Puerto Rico",
                :PS => "Territorios Palestinos",
                :PT => "Portugal",
                :PW => "Palau",
                :PY => "Paraguay",
                :QA => "Qatar",
                :QO => "Territorios alejados de Oceanía",
                :RE => "Reunión",
                :RO => "Rumanía",
                :RS => "Serbia",
                :RU => "Rusia",
                :RW => "Ruanda",
                :SA => "Arabia Saudí",
                :SB => "Islas Salomón",
                :SC => "Seychelles",
                :SD => "Sudán",
                :SE => "Suecia",
                :SG => "Singapur",
                :SH => "Santa Elena",
                :SI => "Eslovenia",
                :SJ => "Svalbard y Jan Mayen",
                :SK => "Eslovaquia",
                :SL => "Sierra Leona",
                :SM => "San Marino",
                :SN => "Senegal",
                :SO => "Somalia",
                :SR => "Surinam",
                :SS => "SS",
                :ST => "Santo Tomé y Príncipe",
                :SV => "El Salvador",
                :SX => "Sint Maarten",
                :SY => "Siria",
                :SZ => "Suazilandia",
                :TA => "Tristán da Cunha",
                :TC => "Islas Turcas y Caicos",
                :TD => "Chad",
                :TF => "Territorios Australes Franceses",
                :TG => "Togo",
                :TH => "Tailandia",
                :TJ => "Tayikistán",
                :TK => "Tokelau",
                :TL => "Timor Oriental",
                :TM => "Turkmenistán",
                :TN => "Túnez",
                :TO => "Tonga",
                :TR => "Turquía",
                :TT => "Trinidad y Tobago",
                :TV => "Tuvalu",
                :TW => "Taiwán",
                :TZ => "Tanzania",
                :UA => "Ucrania",
                :UG => "Uganda",
                :UM => "Islas menores alejadas de los Estados Unidos",
                :US => "Estados Unidos",
                :UY => "Uruguay",
                :UZ => "Uzbekistán",
                :VA => "Ciudad del Vaticano",
                :VC => "San Vicente y las Granadinas",
                :VE => "Venezuela",
                :VG => "Islas Vírgenes Británicas",
                :VI => "Islas Vírgenes de los Estados Unidos",
                :VN => "Vietnam",
                :VU => "Vanuatu",
                :WF => "Wallis y Futuna",
                :WS => "Samoa",
                :YE => "Yemen",
                :YT => "Mayotte",
                :ZA => "Sudáfrica",
                :ZM => "Zambia",
                :ZW => "Zimbabue",
                :ZZ => "Región desconocida"
        }

      }
    }
```

localized_country.es_PE.rb

```
    #encoding: UTF-8
    { :es_PE => {

        :countries => {
                :AC => "Isla de la Ascensión",
                :AD => "Andorra",
                :AE => "Emiratos Árabes Unidos",
                :AF => "Afganistán",
                :AG => "Antigua y Barbuda",
                :AI => "Anguila",
                :AL => "Albania",
                :AM => "Armenia",
                :AN => "Antillas Neerlandesas",
                :AO => "Angola",
                :AQ => "Antártida",
                :AR => "Argentina",
                :AS => "Samoa Americana",
                :AT => "Austria",
                :AU => "Australia",
                :AW => "Aruba",
                :AX => "Islas Åland",
                :AZ => "Azerbaiyán",
                :BA => "Bosnia-Herzegovina",
                :BB => "Barbados",
                :BD => "Bangladesh",
                :BE => "Bélgica",
                :BF => "Burkina Faso",
                :BG => "Bulgaria",
                :BH => "Bahréin",
                :BI => "Burundi",
                :BJ => "Benín",
                :BL => "San Bartolomé",
                :BM => "Bermudas",
                :BN => "Brunéi",
                :BO => "Bolivia",
                :BQ => "BQ",
                :BR => "Brasil",
                :BS => "Bahamas",
                :BT => "Bután",
                :BV => "Isla Bouvet",
                :BW => "Botsuana",
                :BY => "Bielorrusia",
                :BZ => "Belice",
                :CA => "Canadá",
                :CC => "Islas Cocos",
                :CD => "República Democrática del Congo",
                :CF => "República Centroafricana",
                :CG => "Congo - Brazzaville",
                :CH => "Suiza",
                :CI => "Costa de Marfil",
                :CK => "Islas Cook",
                :CL => "Chile",
                :CM => "Camerún",
                :CN => "China",
                :CO => "Colombia",
                :CP => "Isla Clipperton",
                :CR => "Costa Rica",
                :CS => "Serbia y Montenegro",
                :CU => "Cuba",
                :CV => "Cabo Verde",
                :CW => "CW",
                :CX => "Isla Christmas",
                :CY => "Chipre",
                :CZ => "República Checa",
                :DE => "Alemania",
                :DG => "Diego García",
                :DJ => "Yibuti",
                :DK => "Dinamarca",
                :DM => "Dominica",
                :DO => "República Dominicana",
                :DZ => "Argelia",
                :EA => "Ceuta y Melilla",
                :EC => "Ecuador",
                :EE => "Estonia",
                :EG => "Egipto",
                :EH => "Sáhara Occidental",
                :ER => "Eritrea",
                :ES => "España",
                :ET => "Etiopía",
                :EU => "Unión Europea",
                :FI => "Finlandia",
                :FJ => "Fiyi",
                :FK => "Islas Malvinas",
                :FM => "Micronesia",
                :FO => "Islas Feroe",
                :FR => "Francia",
                :GA => "Gabón",
                :GB => "Reino Unido",
                :GD => "Granada",
                :GE => "Georgia",
                :GF => "Guayana Francesa",
                :GG => "Guernsey",
                :GH => "Ghana",
                :GI => "Gibraltar",
                :GL => "Groenlandia",
                :GM => "Gambia",
                :GN => "Guinea",
                :GP => "Guadalupe",
                :GQ => "Guinea Ecuatorial",
                :GR => "Grecia",
                :GS => "Islas Georgia del Sur y Sandwich del Sur",
                :GT => "Guatemala",
                :GU => "Guam",
                :GW => "Guinea-Bissau",
                :GY => "Guyana",
                :HK => "Región Administrativa Especial de Hong Kong de la República Popular China",
                :HM => "Islas Heard y McDonald",
                :HN => "Honduras",
                :HR => "Croacia",
                :HT => "Haití",
                :HU => "Hungría",
                :IC => "Islas Canarias",
                :ID => "Indonesia",
                :IE => "Irlanda",
                :IL => "Israel",
                :IM => "Isla de Man",
                :IN => "India",
                :IO => "Territorio Británico del Océano Índico",
                :IQ => "Iraq",
                :IR => "Irán",
                :IS => "Islandia",
                :IT => "Italia",
                :JE => "Jersey",
                :JM => "Jamaica",
                :JO => "Jordania",
                :JP => "Japón",
                :KE => "Kenia",
                :KG => "Kirguistán",
                :KH => "Camboya",
                :KI => "Kiribati",
                :KM => "Comoras",
                :KN => "San Cristóbal y Nieves",
                :KP => "Corea del Norte",
                :KR => "Corea del Sur",
                :KW => "Kuwait",
                :KY => "Islas Caimán",
                :KZ => "Kazajistán",
                :LA => "Laos",
                :LB => "Líbano",
                :LC => "Santa Lucía",
                :LI => "Liechtenstein",
                :LK => "Sri Lanka",
                :LR => "Liberia",
                :LS => "Lesoto",
                :LT => "Lituania",
                :LU => "Luxemburgo",
                :LV => "Letonia",
                :LY => "Libia",
                :MA => "Marruecos",
                :MC => "Mónaco",
                :MD => "Moldavia",
                :ME => "Montenegro",
                :MF => "San Martín",
                :MG => "Madagascar",
                :MH => "Islas Marshall",
                :MK => "Macedonia",
                :ML => "Mali",
                :MM => "Myanmar [Birmania]",
                :MN => "Mongolia",
                :MO => "Región Administrativa Especial de Macao de la República Popular China",
                :MP => "Islas Marianas del Norte",
                :MQ => "Martinica",
                :MR => "Mauritania",
                :MS => "Montserrat",
                :MT => "Malta",
                :MU => "Mauricio",
                :MV => "Maldivas",
                :MW => "Malaui",
                :MX => "México",
                :MY => "Malasia",
                :MZ => "Mozambique",
                :NA => "Namibia",
                :NC => "Nueva Caledonia",
                :NE => "Níger",
                :NF => "Isla Norfolk",
                :NG => "Nigeria",
                :NI => "Nicaragua",
                :NL => "Países Bajos",
                :NO => "Noruega",
                :NP => "Nepal",
                :NR => "Nauru",
                :NU => "Isla Niue",
                :NZ => "Nueva Zelanda",
                :OM => "Omán",
                :PA => "Panamá",
                :PE => "Perú",
                :PF => "Polinesia Francesa",
                :PG => "Papúa Nueva Guinea",
                :PH => "Filipinas",
                :PK => "Pakistán",
                :PL => "Polonia",
                :PM => "San Pedro y Miquelón",
                :PN => "Islas Pitcairn",
                :PR => "Puerto Rico",
                :PS => "Territorios Palestinos",
                :PT => "Portugal",
                :PW => "Palau",
                :PY => "Paraguay",
                :QA => "Qatar",
                :QO => "Territorios alejados de Oceanía",
                :RE => "Reunión",
                :RO => "Rumanía",
                :RS => "Serbia",
                :RU => "Rusia",
                :RW => "Ruanda",
                :SA => "Arabia Saudí",
                :SB => "Islas Salomón",
                :SC => "Seychelles",
                :SD => "Sudán",
                :SE => "Suecia",
                :SG => "Singapur",
                :SH => "Santa Elena",
                :SI => "Eslovenia",
                :SJ => "Svalbard y Jan Mayen",
                :SK => "Eslovaquia",
                :SL => "Sierra Leona",
                :SM => "San Marino",
                :SN => "Senegal",
                :SO => "Somalia",
                :SR => "Surinam",
                :SS => "SS",
                :ST => "Santo Tomé y Príncipe",
                :SV => "El Salvador",
                :SX => "Sint Maarten",
                :SY => "Siria",
                :SZ => "Suazilandia",
                :TA => "Tristán da Cunha",
                :TC => "Islas Turcas y Caicos",
                :TD => "Chad",
                :TF => "Territorios Australes Franceses",
                :TG => "Togo",
                :TH => "Tailandia",
                :TJ => "Tayikistán",
                :TK => "Tokelau",
                :TL => "Timor Oriental",
                :TM => "Turkmenistán",
                :TN => "Túnez",
                :TO => "Tonga",
                :TR => "Turquía",
                :TT => "Trinidad y Tobago",
                :TV => "Tuvalu",
                :TW => "Taiwán",
                :TZ => "Tanzania",
                :UA => "Ucrania",
                :UG => "Uganda",
                :UM => "Islas menores alejadas de los Estados Unidos",
                :US => "Estados Unidos",
                :UY => "Uruguay",
                :UZ => "Uzbekistán",
                :VA => "Ciudad del Vaticano",
                :VC => "San Vicente y las Granadinas",
                :VE => "Venezuela",
                :VG => "Islas Vírgenes Británicas",
                :VI => "Islas Vírgenes de los Estados Unidos",
                :VN => "Vietnam",
                :VU => "Vanuatu",
                :WF => "Wallis y Futuna",
                :WS => "Samoa",
                :YE => "Yemen",
                :YT => "Mayotte",
                :ZA => "Sudáfrica",
                :ZM => "Zambia",
                :ZW => "Zimbabue",
                :ZZ => "Región desconocida"
        }

      }
    }
```

Comment: Probably be worth showing the contents of your translation files.

Comment: Done that with 2 of them. (But they are just copy and pasted with the same strings)

Comment: ...yeeep, looks like it. Still, worth having so we could double check (sorry, I don't have any more ideas).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cite your error with `translation missing: es-PE.countries`.

The file is named `localized_country_select.es_PE.rb`

The underscorse/hyphens might be cause of the problem ... or might be just a typo.

Comment: You are really right on this one! Thanks a lot. Just found it out myself 1 minute ago. The error was a little bit deeper. Our locales are named es_PE, es_MX etc. but gettext_i18n_rails makes it es-PE in a new version of the gem. In this commit: https://github.com/grosser/gettext_i18n_rails/commit/b2d594b6d37a43e94cb42822415259d428713369